# How determine which control was clicked in WPF UserControl?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF user contol, in which I have a StackPanel. To this panel I'm adding programatically a label this way (Container is the name of StackPanel):

```
public void Insert(string Value)
{
     Label l = new Label();
     l.Content = Value;
     Container.Children.Add(l);
}
```

Now I want to provide some public event SelectedIndexChange, when user clicks on label. Now I have a problem how determine which label was clicked. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in `Insert` you add the line:

```
l.Click += ClickHandler;
```

then the first argument of ClickHandler will be the control that raised the Click event.

e.g. If your handler is:

```
private void ClickHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){...};
```

then `sender` will be the label that was clicked.

You could alternatively look at `e.OriginalSource`.

Answer (score 0):

I Guess You Can Use This Code

```
 l.MouseClick+= MouseClickHandler;
```

And Switch Between Lables

Example:

```
private void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton==  MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                Label l = (Label)e.Source;
                switch (l.Name)
                {
                    case "lable1":
                        int a = 10;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```